# Ciphertext-only vs known-ciphertext attack

Tags: encryption

From what I understand, "ciphertext-only attack" and "known-ciphertext attack" are both synonyms for an attack in which the attacker knows a number of ciphertexts and only those ciphertexts, e.g. has no idea about the corresponding plaintexts and has no way of querying the encryption function either.

Is this understanding correct? If no, what is the difference between the two? If yes, is there a scientific (as in: scientifically citable) source that explicitly states this equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

A [quick check of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext-only_attack) indicates they are the same thing as I suspected just from their names.  This isn't very scientifically citable, but I would assume for the cryptographic community this would be common knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that both of those terms describe the same attack.  But there are two distinct types of cyphertext attacks; they are the "cyphertext-only attack" and "chosen cyphertext attack".  They vary in the amount of power they have to a cryptanalyst.  In the cyphertext-only attack, all you know is some output came from the algorithm, but you know nothing else about it.  This is the standard position assumed of any attacker.  In the chosen cyphertext attack, the attacker creates cyphertext of his or her choosing, input it into a black box containing both the algorithm and key used to encrypt it, and receives the output.

A Cryptography Primer lists the following four basic categories of attack on an algorithm:

- Cyphertext-only attack
- Known plaintext attack
- Chosen plaintext attack
- Chosen cyphertext attack

[A Cryptography Primer, by Philip N. Klein](http://cs.brown.edu/~pnk/). Publisher: Cambridge University Press. Pub. Date: March 31, 2014. Print ISBN: 978-1-107-01788-7